# Referencing list to remove string values

Tags: python, replace, ord

The following `def clean_sheet_title` function references `INVALID_TITLE_CHAR` and `INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP` to strip out invalid characters and limits the `title` to 31 characters -

```
# This strips characters that are invalid to Excel
INVALID_TITLE_CHARS = ["]", "[", "*", ":", "?", "/", "\\", "'"]
INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP = {ord(x): "" for x in INVALID_TITLE_CHARS}

# How would I remove strings, as well as the characters from INVALID_TITLE_CHARS?
INVALID_TITLE_NAMES = ["zz_ FeeRelationship", " Family"]

def clean_sheet_title(title):
    title = title or ""
    title = title.strip()
    title = title.translate(INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP)
    return title[:31]
```

My question is how I would expand this to also remove strings from within the `INVALID_TITLE_NAMES`list?

**What I've tried:** I have tried making the following update to `def clean_sheet_title` however this makes no difference to `title` -

```
INVALID_TITLE_CHARS = ["]", "[", "*", ":", "?", "/", "\\", "'"]
INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP = {ord(x): "" for x in INVALID_TITLE_CHARS}

INVALID_TITLE_NAMES = ["zz_ FeeRelationship", "Family"]


def clean_sheet_title(title):
    title = title or ""
    title = title.strip()
    title = title.translate(INVALID_TITLE_CHAR_MAP, "")
    for name in INVALID_TITLE_NAMES:
        title = title.replace(name, "")
    return title[:31]
```

**Examples:**

- Current function ability - if `title` == `Courtenay:Family` then currently the `def clean_sheet_title` will ensure the title will be `Courtenay Family`.
- Desired function ability - Sometimes `title` can be prefixed or suffixed with either `zz_ FeeRelationship` or `Family`, in both cases, these strings should be dropped. E.g. `zz_ FeeRelationship Courtenay:Family` would become `Courtenay`

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of the behavior that you want?

Comment: Sure @ScottHunter - currently `Courtenay: Family` is replaced with `Courtenay Family`. and `zz_ FeeRelationship Courtenay: Family` is replaced with `zz_ FeeRelationship Courtenay Family`. You can probably see the pattern; every `title` value is either prefixed or suffixed with `zz_ FeeRelationship` or `Family` and often contains invalid characters (values in `INVALID_TITLE_CHARTS`) which are what I am trying to remove. The output should be `Courtenay Family` in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
for name in INVALID_TITLE_NAMES:
    title = title.replace(name, "")
```

Is that the result you are trying to achieve? It should replace each invalid name in `title` with an empty string.

Comment: Firstly, welcome, Bob! I appreciate your response. I have updated my question to show what I tried, using your method, however, it doesn't seem to strip out any strings. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: This won't work because string methods return a copy instead of modifying the string in-place. You want to do `title = title.replace(...)`

Comment: Thanks for editing it Pranav, my bad there

Comment: Thanks for both your input. I tried `title = title.replace(INVALID_TITLE_NAMES, "")`, however get a `TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not list`. Did I misunderstand your suggestion(s)?

Comment: What you did isn't working because it you have to pass in each `str` object in the list one at a time into `str.replace`, not the entire list. Just copy the code in the answer above and it should work.

Comment: The code above does not reference `str.replace`.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? Because I'm pretty confident my answer has `str.replace`.

Comment: Oh, my bad; I wasn't clear. when we call `title.replace`, that is calling the `replace` function of a `str` object. Hence, `str.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to match any of your keywords or characters and replace them with an empty string:

```
import re

INVALID_TITLE_CHARS = ["]", "[", "*", ":", "?", "/", "\\", "'"]
INVALID_TITLE_NAMES = ["zz_ FeeRelationship", " Family"]

inv_char_grp = re.escape("".join(INVALID_TITLE_CHARS))
inv_name_grp = "|".join(re.escape(name) for name in INVALID_TITLE_NAMES)


regex = f"[{inv_char_grp}]|{inv_name_grp}"


title = "zz_ FeeRelationship Courtenay: Family"
result = re.sub(regex, "", title)
print(result)
```

which prints `Courtenay`

---

An explanation of the regular expressions:

- Since we have special characters in `INVALID_TITLE_CHARS`, they need to be escaped so that the regex engine recognizes them as *literal* characters instead of using their special meaning. So we join all the characters in `INVALID_TITLE_CHARS`, then use `re.escape` to escape the resulting string. This gives us the regex `inv_char_grp = r"\]\[\*:\?/\\'"`
- We wrap that in `[` and `]` to denote that we want to match *one of any of those characters* using `f"[{inv_char_grp}]".
- We also want to match any of the names in `INVALID_TITLE_NAMES`. Since these are whole strings, we won't use a character group for them. Instead, we can use the `|` operator to indicate that we want to match any of its operands. Also remember to escape the names in case they contain any special characters.

The final regex we get is

```
[\]\[\*:\?/\\']|zz_\ FeeRelationship|\ Family

[\]\[\*:\?/\\']                                : Any of these chars ][*:?/\
               |                               : Or
                zz_\ FeeRelationship           : Exactly zz_, then a space, then FeeRelationship
                                    |          : Or
                                     \ Family  : Exactly one space, then Family
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/pbmXqd/1)